# How to filter nested documents with mongodb c# driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I have the next query that filters a nested array document in a collection and isn't working (always is returning false):

```
var collection = MongoClientSingleton.GetInstance().GetCollection<Access> 
("access");

var filters = Builders<Access>.Filter.Eq("modules", new BsonDocument { { 
"value", val }, { "enabled", true }, { "type", type } });

 return collection.Find(filters).Any();
```

I'm having success when I use linq to build the filter:

```
var filters = Builders<Access>.Filter.Where(a => a.modules.Any(m => m.value == val && m.enabled == true && m.type == type));
```

But I want do the filter more like the first code shown (with the BsonDocument class).

The class struct of Access and Module are like this:

```
public class Access 
{
    ...

    public List<Module> modules {get; set; }

    ...
}

public class Module 
{
    ...

    public string value { get; set; }
    public bool enabled { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

for complex or nested query, you can try aggregate function. here's a good read about it
https://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/mongodb-aggregation-framework-examples-in-c

Comment: Helpful link, but in this examples didn't work with nested array type documents..